# What's wrong in my approach in a problem of game of death in a circle?

Tags: c++, stl, josephus

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void safe(int n,int k,int a[])
{
    vector<int>s(a+0,a+n);
    vector<int>b(a+0,a+n);
    while(s.size()>1)
    {
        int r;
        r=s.size();
       int count=1;
        while(count<=r)
        {
            b[count%r]=0;
            count=count+k;
        }
    b.erase(remove(b.begin(),b.end(),0),b.end());
    s=b;    
    }
    
    for(int x:s)
    {
        cout<<x<<"\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;
        int *a=new int[n];
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            a[j-1]=j;
        }
        if(n>2)
        {
        safe(n,k,a);
        }
        else if(n==2)
        {
     cout<<a[1]<<"\n";
        }
        else
        cout<<a[0]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Input:

```
4
4 2
5 2
2 1
50 10
```

Output:

```
1
3
2
19  --> it should be 36
```

If you don't know this problem
Description of question:
There are n people standing in a circle (numbered clockwise 1 to n) waiting to be executed. The counting begins at point 1 in the circle and proceeds around the circle in a fixed direction (clockwise). In each step, a certain number of people are skipped and the next person is executed. The elimination proceeds around the circle (which is becoming smaller and smaller as the executed people are removed), until only the last person remains, who is given freedom.
Given the total number of persons n and a number k which indicates that k-1 persons are skipped and kth person is killed in circle. The task is to choose the place in the initial circle so that you are the last one remaining and so survive.
Consider if n = 5 and k = 2, then the safe position is 3.
Firstly, the person at position 2 is killed, then person at position 4 is killed, then person at position 1 is killed. Finally, the person at position 5 is killed. So the person at position 3 survives.

Comment: Wrong output on giving 50 10 as input ,i must get 36 ,but it's giving 19.I scratched my head for long but couldn't get it that what's wrong,can you see?

Comment: `int *a=new int[n];` -- Why are you doing this when you could have simply used `std::vector<int> a(n);`?  Right now, that loop leaks memory.

Comment: I think goes wrong right from the start because it always kills the first person, I believe it should kill the kth person.

Comment: btw bits/stdc++ already includes algorithm and vector

Comment: And it also slows downs your build time s by close to an an order of magnitude because it includes the entire freaking C++ Standard Library. That's a <expletive deleted> load of code that needs to be loaded from disk and compiled just so you can get a few extra identifiers. It's not worth using. The time saved typing fewer includes is eaten up by at most two compiles.

Comment: One thing wrong is that you are using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` which is not a standard header file.

Comment: The `using namespace std;` should be avoided.  List the items individually to avoid bringing in *all* the symbols in `std`.  Example:  `using std::cout;`

Comment: Not using namespace std ,like seriously I have to type std again and again,if it has any advantage?

Comment: @Mayanktiwari Yes, it's definitely worth the effort of saying `std::` everywhere. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Thanks ,I got that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution, hopefully the comments make it clear. There's no need to allocate an `int[]` and copy it into the vector, you can init the vector directly with `iota`. Likewise you can remove elements as you go, rather than zeroing and removing as a later step.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void safe(int n, int k) {
  vector<int> s(n);
  // Init the vector 1..n
  iota(s.begin(), s.end(), 1);
  int i = 0;
  // While more than one survive...
  while (s.size() > 1) {
    // Skip forward (k-1)
    i = (i + k - 1) % s.size();
    // Kill the next one
    s.erase(s.begin() + i);
  }
  for (int x : s) {
    cout << x << "\n";
  }
}

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    if (n > 2) {
      safe(n, k);
    } else if (n == 2) {
      cout << 2 << "\n";
    } else
      cout << 1 << "\n";
  }
}
```